# Custom View: during drag dynamically calculate and draw rectangle width towards the next rectangle

Tags: android, drawing, android-view, android-canvas, android-custom-view

For instance, I have three rectangles (`RectF`) on a canvas. 
The middle one *has a different width* than two others. Assume that I have all text and rectangle bounds already calculated and cached.

**So, the question is:** 
How I can change the width of the selected rectangle dynamically (leaning on distance) to the width of the next rectangle while dragging towards it?

In custom `View` using:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
   ...
}

override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent) {
   when(event) {

       ...

       MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
           ...
       }  
   }
}
```

I can not figure out how to calculate it in the right way. If you have an idea how to solve it, please let me know.

**How it should look:** (swiping between 1 and 2)

[image: representation]

Comment: Sorry I cannot be of more help (I'm moving house) but if you are drawing the Vectors of your boxes yourself, then it is easy, if not, it can be done but can be very complex." `You say: Assume that I have all text and rectangle bounds already calculated and cached. `" Then change and Draw them, You use the onDraw() method (override) of the Canvas to dynamically calculate and draw the new configuration (even an previously one). Images always help in these situations, better still gif. (hint it's not difficult) –

Comment: Yeah, sounds easy, but when you have `RectF` and its coordinates (`top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`), how I could change the size properly leaning on distance & size between 2 rectangles?

Comment: Give it a try, we can fix it, put the effort in and you will most likely solve it yourself. Simple geometry. Show your code, don't be embarrassed. (hint #1 [rect overlap detection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect) ) {getRect().intersect()}